# Unable to start kiwix on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wikipedia, ubuntu-18.04

Kiwix software doesn't start when I double click on it.

And when I try to run it from the terminal, I get the following error;

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/user_name/Documents/kiwix/xulrunner/libxul.so:
/home/user_name/Documents/kiwix/xulrunner/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)
Couldn't load XP,COM.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/libz.so.1 xulrunner/libz.so.1`  in a terminal window.